# How to prevent core-activate event in core-list when item's paper-icon-button is clicked

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I've a `core-list` with a custom element for each item:

```dart
<core-list-dart data={{data}} on-core-activate={{onCoreActivate}}>
  <template>
    <person-item item={{model}}></person-item>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

The custom element (`person-item`) has two buttons:

```dart
<polymer-element name="person-item">
  <template>
    <paper-item>
      <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
      <button on-click={{onItemClick}}>Click me!</button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-click={{onItemClick}}>Click me!</paper-icon-button>
    </paper-item>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="person_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

- When I click the item as expected the `onCoreActivate` method is called.
- When I click the item `button` as expected the `onItemClick` method is called and the `onCoreActivate` method is not called.
- When I click the item `paper-icon-button` the `onItemClick` method is called but also the `onCoreActivate` method is called.

How can I prevent the `core-activate` event in the third case?

I've tried to prevent the propagation of `click` event from the `onItemClick` method but without success.

I've also tried to prevent the `tap` event propagation but without success.

Comment: Do you have an event handler method for `paper-icon-button`? You can try calling `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in this method.

Comment: Tried all of three without success.

Comment: You could try to add an `on-tap` handler and try it there too.

Comment: Do you think the second case is due to https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/lib/core_list_dart.dart#L389 ?

Comment: I guess so. Is `onCoreActivate` executed before or after `onItemClick`?

Comment: It is executed after. As workaround I've added a flag that I set when the click is intercepted then I discard the selection and reset it if the flag is set. Ugly but working.

Comment: If it executed after I would still expect calling `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatPropagation` to have an effect. Have you tried to call all three on the event in the `onTap` event handler? I guess this has something to do with the `onTap` polyfill (I assume they are still not native browser events but a JavaScript implementation)

Comment: Tried also calling all the three, not working.

Comment: I've open an issue about: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

I remember having some ugly hacks where I was saving a flag for a given duration when the user was pressing a button in a list item. But the last time I checked (core_elements 0.4), handling click on the list itself (CoreList) was working (i.e. not on the item). Pseudo code below where I check the target item pressed by id (in my case it is a PaperIconButton but that is not relevant). I get the core-activate event when user tap somewhere else in the list but don't get it when the user tap on the button.

```dart
CoreList list = $['list'];
list.onClick.listen((Event e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target is Element) {
    if (target.id == "play") {
      // prevent sending the core-activate event
      e.preventDefault();

      // ... do my stuff here
    }
  }
});
```

Then you might wonder how we know which item the button belongs to. There are many ways. I personally store that in a data-id attribute in the item itself that I found from the targeted button ancestors.